# Why are rx.text / rx.observe / rx.etc not available (RxSwift)

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I've created a simple project with Cocoapods and installed RxSwift and RxCocoa.

I've written this code:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //self.field.rx. (only suggests `base`)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

so I should be able to get `self.field.rx.text` right? But I only get `self.field.rx.base`

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you tell us what version you're using? It might be, if you're using an older version, that it's `rx_text` instead of `rx.text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `import RxCocoa` at the top too

Comment: No he doesn't, he has only import for UKit and RxSwift

Comment: @pableiros a new problem arises. If I type (for example) searchBar.rx.text., I get no more suggestions. So it stops after text?